# Adding Integers within a list

Tags: java

I am trying to add Integers inside a list together with one line.  The problem is that adding Integers in a string return an object itself and not the sum of the Integers.

For example, I have the string `3 4 6 2 7 4`.

I want to add all of the numbers together like so: `3 + 4 + 6 + 2 + 7 + 4` =  `26`.  I have tried:

```
for (String number : after.split ("\\s+")) {
       int v = Integer.parseInt (number);
       System.out.println (v);
       numbers.add (v);
}
```

Instead of 26, I get `[3 4 6 2 7 4]`.  How do I get the result of the sum of the integers rather than the Object?

Comment: It seems that you have declared `numbers` as a `List<Integer>` or something like that. The `add()` method therfore just adds the passed integer to the list, id does not make a mathematical _add_ operation. The answers below already show you how to sum up the numbers correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this

```
int sum = 0; //Declare a variable to keep track of your sum
for (String number : after.split ("\\s+")) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt (number);
    System.out.println (v);
    numbers.add(v);
    sum += v; //Each iteration of your loop add the current int to your sum
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Currently you are just taking each int and adding it to a list. If you want a sum of those values within the list you need another variable to represent this. In my example I have used an int variable named sum. Each time you add an int to your list you will also add it to your current sum value.

Comment: Man, I never thought any of my questions would get this popular!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the List is not the same as adding up integer values. You are looking for

```
  numbers +=v;
```

where numbers in an int value and adding up each value `v` in the loop to it.

```
int numbers =0;
 for (String number : after.split ("\\s+")) {
                    int v = Integer.parseInt (number);
                    System.out.println (v);
                    numbers +=v;
                }
System.out.println(numbers);
```

And

`numbers +=v;`  is a shorthand for `numbers = numbers+v`

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 and [streams](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), you'll be able to do this in one line :

```
int sum = Arrays.stream("1 2 3".split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Comment: Good call, I'm not familiar with any if the Java 8 stuff as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) like so

```
public static long add(String in) {
    long acc = 0;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        acc += Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken().trim());
    }
    return acc;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(add("3 4 6 2 7 4"));
}
```

Which does output 26.